# svn update seems to have trashed some local modificaftions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a developer that made a bunch of changes to a working copy.  It is a little hard to trace back in time all that happened, but here is what I think that happened.

1) we created a branch off of trunk and the developer created a working copy from that branch

2) we did a revert to a revision in the trunk that removed the section of code that that developer was working on

3) we deleted the branch that that developer was working on and created a new one off of trunk by the same name.

4) she updated her working copy and it deleted the local files.

They appear to be lost.  Is there any way that they are still referenced in her local working copy and can be recovered?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry but it's probably gone unless you have any sort of data recovery tool.

This is completely outside the realm of subversion.

:/